# Extract Signal Curve From Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

I have the following photo:
[image]

and want to extract the ECG signal, but the curve may overlap other things in the image. I have tried thresholding the image, performing opening, searching for contours and selecting the biggest one. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
    
img = cv2.imread('frame.png')
h,w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h,w), np.uint8)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# Search for contours and select the biggest one and draw it on mask
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)

res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(res,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find all non white pixels
non_zero = cv2.findNonZero(thresh)

# Transform all other pixels in non_white to white
for i in range(0, len(non_zero)):
    first_x = non_zero[i][0][0]
    first_y = non_zero[i][0][1]
    first = res[first_y, first_x]
    res[first_y, first_x] = 255

cv2.imshow('img', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But it doesn't work. The output still have a lot of noise. The curve is also not continuous and unclear.I need the extracted line to have a more distinct colour in order to perform the other tasks. How can I improve this curve extraction task?
[image]

Comment: discard all that. -- you could first mask off the circular "picture". or not. yes, the curve may be unrecoverable where it overlaps the circular "picture". -- for the curve, simply threshold very close to the uniform color of that curve (around RGB ~180), so you only get those pixels. then, for each pixel column along the curve, find the median or mean pixel index (y-value).

Comment: I have other pictures that have most of the lines overlapping the noises, so this probably will not work.

Comment: if you think that could be an issue, you should provide such pictures. I might demonstrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach. I have done it in small steps so that you can see what I get after each phase and you can select parts that work and adapt parts that don't.

I am interspersing the result/debug images, but the code works if you just copy the parts and paste them contiguously:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image as greyscale
im = cv2.imread('ecg.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Threshold to pure black and white
_, thr = cv2.threshold(im, 150,255,type=cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-thr.png', thr)
```

[image]

```
# Erode so that thin objects disappear
SE = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
eroded = cv2.morphologyEx(thr, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, SE)
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-eroded.png', eroded)
```

[image]

```
# Dilate so that remaining thinned objects return more or less to original size before thinning
dilated = cv2.morphologyEx(eroded, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, SE)
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-dilated.png', dilated)
```

[image]

```
# Remove all the fat objects from the original
thr[dilated > 0] = 0
cv2.imwrite('DEBUG-nonECGremoved.png', thr)
```

[image]

```
# Remove small artefacts
res = thr
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thr, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for i,cnt in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area < 100:
       #print(f'Removing contour({i}), area:{area}, contour: {cnt}')
       cv2.drawContours(res, [cnt], -1, 0, -1)

# Save result
cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

[image]